# Countdownlatch and further synchronisation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, countdownlatch

Supposedly I have the following class definition, when one thread wants to set a for multiple (potentially) waiting threads:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private CountDownLatch gate;

    public A(int a) {
        a = 1;
        gate = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public int getA() {
        latch.await();
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
        gate.countDown();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that a needs to be volatile, but I am not sure… Could someone please share why, if at all, there needs to be an extra synchronization around getA, or a needs to be volatile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `a` doesn't need to be volatile because `countDown()` loades and stores into volatile `state` variable of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` which is used inside `CountDownLatch`. Volatile store triggers a memory-barrier ([great in-depth article about Memory Barriers and etc in JSR-133](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html)). And according to the JMM all previous stores (to other variables) would be visible to other threads. 
**assylias** is right, it would be true only if you call `setA()` once, because you construct latch as `new CountDownLatch(1)`.

Comment: Ah, so there are volatile reads/writes inside the latch's state. That in turn is a full barrier so the changes are propagated across caches etc. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly this happens.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

> Until the count reaches zero, actions in a thread prior to calling `countDown()` happen-before actions following a successful return from a corresponding `await()` in another thread.

So you don't need extra synchronisation if you only call `setA` once. If you call it a second time, because the count will already be 0, you won't get the same guarantee.

If the expected use is to only call `setA` once you could throw an exception if it is called more than once to enforce that contract (although checking the count AND assigning a new value to a atomically may be tricky without additional synchronisation).

If you are happy that `setA` can be called more than once then you need additional synchronisation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How is this memory consistency achieved? Seems to me that the latch does not have any relationship to class A to be able to synchronize the state of a across multiple threads...

Comment: `How is this memory consistency achieved?` I described this in my answer :)

Comment: @Bober02 All the reading threads (calling `getA`) will read `a` *after* `await` completes (program order). The writing thread (the one and only thread that calls `setA`) is calling `countDown` *after* writing to `a` (program order). Because *happens-before* relationships are transitive, the guarantee given in the javadoc means that the write to `a` happens-before the reads of `a`. All this assumes `setA` is only called once.

Comment: Agreed, but this is still high level. Volatile writes/barriers were more down my alley

Comment: @Bober02 I'm not sure what you expect - working with happens-before relationships is enough in this case. You may refer to processor barrier instructions but these are not part of the Java Memory Model (even if JVMs generally use them to implement the JMM).